# What's the difference between Java Util Function and Collections4 Transformer?

Tags: java

What is the difference of the interfaces:

- [`org.apache.commons.collections4.Transformer`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/Transformer.html)
- [`java.util.function.Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)

Aren't they doing a similar action?:

T --> doing stuff --> R

Assume I've got an `User` Object, and I want to let one of these interfaces return me the `loginname` as a `String` from that object. I could use both?

```
@Override
    public String apply(User user) {
        return user.getLoginname();
    }
```

or

```
@Override
    public String transform(User user) {
        return user.getLoginname();
    }
```

Comment: The quick difference: one of the two interfaces is annotated with [@FunctionalInterface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), the other is not.  You would rarely directly @Override the `apply()` function.  You would just use `User::getLoginname` to obtain a `Function` interface object.  Oh, any you can `.compose()` and `.andThen()` the functional interface one.

Answer (score 3):

These two interfaces have equivalent function -- they take an object of some type as input, and return an object of some, possibly different, type.  `Transformer` has somewhat narrower documented scope, in the sense that "compute a transformation of" is, to me, a particular case of "compute a function of", but that's weak.

The most important difference between these interfaces is how instances can be used with other objects.  They are *not* interchangeable.  Thus, if you want to use a `TransformedList` then it has to be defined in terms of a `Transformer`, not a `Function`.  If you want to obtain a `flatMap` from a `Stream` then you need a `Function`, not a `Transformer`.

Because they are basically just different names for the same idea, however, it is trivial to write an adapter to enable you to use one type in a context that requires the other.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference?

The name.

> Aren't they doing a similar action?

Yes.

> I could use both?

Sure, but why rely on [Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) if you can use built-in type?